# How to copy data from one sheet to another sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to copy data from one sheet to another sheet, one of the sheet is actively being updated. Would like to capture data from one sheet entirely to another sheet for log.

Comment: `ctrl+c` then `ctrl+v`

Comment: ctrl+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v (building up on the comment above)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is updated regularly, and want to log the data of a certain moment then use Paste -> Paste values. The cells will then not contain the formulas, but the values of that moment.

Have a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/paste-values-not-formulas-12687b4d-c79f-4137-b0cc-947c229c55b9) for more info.